# Read byte from Serial

Tags: byte, arduino

I´ve made this program that reads info from serial and writes the value binary to 6 LEDs. I don´t feel that it´s the easiest or the fastest way though and that is what I´m really looking for. My code looks like this:

```
boolean enable = false;

void setup()
{
  for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++)
  {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    enable = true;
  }
  if (enable)
  {
    while (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      byte b = Serial.parseInt();
      b = constrain(b, 0, 63);
      byte val = b;
      for (int i = 7; i >= 2; i--)
      {
        if (pow(2, (i-2)) <= val)
        {
          digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
          val -= pow(2, (i-2));
        }
        else
        {
          digitalWrite(i, LOW);
        }
      }
    }
    enable = false;
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

A valid code example would be nice. I´ve tried using PORTD but it does not work.

Comment: The `enable =` bit is useless clutter (unless you were planning to do more with it). Simpler to just do `while (Serial.available() > 0)` and manage your LED states within that as you are.

Comment: I was but I found a better solution than using both the while loop and the boolean "enable". Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use binary operations

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ ) {
   val = ( b >> i ) & 0x1;
   digitalWrite(i, val == 1 ? HIGH : LOW );
}
```

If you plan some serious serial communication have a look into library I created https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/arduino-serial-helper

Comment: Thank you, I´l take a look at that. :)

Comment: Pleasure, I hope it will help.